# Combo box's Selected index changed event not getting fired when any item is selected

Tags: combobox

I am having a form in which there are two combo box and a grid,
i have written filtering code on selectedindex changed event of combo box,SuggestAppend property is set for combo box.when i type a country name eg india and press enter the selected index changed event does not fire immediately,when i click somewhere out then its fires and gives output.
  Please suggest me what to do.Thanks in advance

protected void cbCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCondition();
            Fillgrid();
        }

```
 public string GetCondition()
        {
            string Condition = "";
            if (cbEmployee.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                Condition = Condition + " And reg_no=" + cbEmployee.SelectedValue;
            }

            if (cbCountry.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                Condition = Condition + " And country='" + cbCountry.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
  return Condition;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in the form designer (designer.cs) that the event is declared

this.cbCountry.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cbCountry_SelectedIndexChanged);

if it is not declared you can add it in designer or in the form load

Comment: you mean to say this right??<cc3:ComboBox ID="cbCountry" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" TabIndex="2"
                                            OnDataBound="cbCountry_DataBound" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        </cc3:ComboBox>

Comment: Oh, sorry I thought it was windows forms.